# How to add additional numbers in simple fraction cancellation example

Tags: fractions

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\newcommand{\strikeout}[1]{% 
  \ifmmode% 
    \tikz[inner sep=0.5pt,baseline] \node [strike out,draw=black,anchor=text]{${}#1{}$};% 
  \else% 
    \tikz[inner sep=0.5pt,baseline] \node [strike out,draw=black,anchor=text]{#1};% 
  \fi% 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\frac{4\strikeout{a}b}{\strikeout{9}}   \times  \frac{\strikeout{6}\strikeout{m}}    {\strikeout{a}c\strikeout{m}}  &=\frac{4b \times 2 }{3c}   \\
                            &= \frac{8b}{3c} \\
                            &=  \frac{8b}{3c}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\newcommand{\strikeout}[1]{% 
  \ifmmode% 
    \tikz[inner sep=0.5pt,baseline] \node [strike out,draw=black,anchor=text]{${}#1{}$};% 
  \else% 
    \tikz[inner sep=0.5pt,baseline] \node [strike out,draw=black,anchor=text]{#1};% 
  \fi% 
}

\newcommand{\uprest}[1]{\!{}^{^{^{#1}}}\!\!}
\newcommand{\downrest}[1]{\!{}_{_{_{_{#1}}}}\!\!}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\frac{4\strikeout{a}b}{\downrest{3}\strikeout{9}}   \times
\frac{\strikeout{6}\uprest{2}\strikeout{m}}{\strikeout{a}c\strikeout{m}}
                               &=\frac{4b \times 2 }{3c}   \\
                               &= \frac{8b}{3c} \\
                               &=  \frac{8b}{3c}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Otherwise, the `cancel` package provides a `\cancelto` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\frac{4\cancel{a}b}{\cancelto{3}{9}}   \times  
\frac{\cancelto{2}{6}\cancel{m}}{\cancel{a}c\cancel{m}}  
                               &=\frac{4b \times 2 }{3c}   \\
                               &= \frac{8b}{3c} \\
                               &=  \frac{8b}{3c}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I notice that  "\cancelto " has an arrow tip which is not desired.

Comment: @mark You're welcome. If it is what you were looking for, please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) for info.